# SQL Server update?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with the following columns:

```
CID   ContractNumber   ContractName    CompanyID  
1     N/200            TAS               13
2     N/201            TAA               1
```

My stored procedure to update this table

```
    @id as int 
    @cnum as nvarchar(50)
    @cname as nvarchar (50)
    @cp as int 

update contracts 
set ContractNumber = @cnum,
    ContractName = @cname,
    CompanyID  = @cp ,
where 
    CID = @id
```

When I update in `contractnumber` column only, the output `@cname` is not supplied and update query will terminate.

Comment: You should edit your question and show the error message.  Also, the `create table` statement might be helpful.

Comment: if you are saying Parameters some times may be empty,use isnull () or coalsece

Comment: procedure or function  'edit' expect '@cname' which was not supplied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you have a `not null` constraint on `ContractName`.  By not supplying a name, the constraint gets violated.

To fix this, arrange the `update` so it keeps existing values if the new value is `NULL`:

```
update contracts 
set ContractNumber = coalesce(@cnum, ContractNumber),
    ContractName = coalesce(@cname, ContractName),
    CompanyID = coalesce(@cp, CompanyID)
where CID = @id;
```